# Multiple server login using Putty with Pywinauto python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, putty, pywinauto

How to logged in to multiple server using pywinauto application? I am using below program for access putty and run the command, This is work for single server when i have defined like 
app = Application ().Start (cmd_line = 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe -ssh user@10.55.167.4')
But while i am passing with for loop to do the same task for another server it does not work.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

server = [ "10.55.167.4", "10.56.127.23" ]
for inser in server:
    print(inser)
    app = Application ().Start (cmd_line = 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe -ssh user@inser')
    putty = app.PuTTY
    putty.Wait ('ready')
    time.sleep (1)
    putty.TypeKeys ("aq@wer")
    putty.TypeKeys ("{ENTER}")
    putty.TypeKeys ("ls")
    putty.TypeKeys ("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: How exactly it does not work? What is the error you get? You should definitely use the actual server IP or host or domain instead of the variable name in your ssh query: `'... putty.exe -ssh user@%s' % inser`. But you really don't need to call putty in this awkward way when excellent ssh modules are available for Python, for example `paramiko`: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html

Comment: Thanks @deeenes , How to capture the console output and save into file for this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pywinauto` is a Python module to automatize graphical user interface (GUI) operations for example to simulate mouse clicking and everything else humans used to do on GUIs to interact with the computer. SSH is a remote access protocol designed primarily for command line and having excellent programmatic support in Python. Putty is a little GUI tool to manage SSH and Telnet connections. Although, based on quick check, I think it is possible to read the console output (you mean in `cmd.com`?) by `pywinauto`, I think your approach is unnecessarily complicated: you don't need to use a GUI tool designed for human interaction to access a protocol with excellent command line and programmatic library support. I suggest you to use `paramiko` which gives a very simple and convenient interface to SSH:

```
import paramiko

def ssh_connect(server, **kwargs):

    client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    # note: here you can give other paremeters
    # like user, port, password, key file, etc.
    # also you can wrap the call below into
    # try/except, you can expect many kinds of
    # errors here, if the address is unreachable,
    # times out, authentication fails, etc.
    client.connect(server, **kwargs)
    return client

servers = ['10.55.167.4', '10.56.127.23']

# connect to all servers
clients = dict((server, ssh_connect(server)) for server in servers)

# execute commands on the servers by the clients, 2 examples:

stdin, stdout, stderr = clients['10.55.167.4'].exec_command('pwd')
print(stdout.read())
# b'/home/denes\n'

stdin, stdout, stderr = clients['10.56.127.23'].exec_command('rm foobar')
print(stderr.read())
# b"rm: cannot remove 'foobar': No such file or directory\n"

# once you finished close the connections
_ = [cl.close() for cl in clients.values()]
```